# Change center of rotation in Java 3D based on mouse location

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, java-3d

I'm using Java and JavaFXPanel to display a 3D model.

Currently I have a 3D model, which I can traverse and rotate around absolutely fine. The center of rotation is set to the center of the model and as such rotation always occurs around there.

Functionality I am currently trying to add a toggle-able mode such then when its true and you click on model it changes the center of rotation to where the mouse was clicked and focuses the camera on that point. Thus when you exit the mode you now rotate around this new location.

My current attempt at handling this process looks somewhat like this:

```
// Register mouse click event handler
scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final MouseEvent me) {
            // Was an object selected?
            final PickResult result = me.getPickResult();
            if (result.getIntersectedNode() instanceof Shape3D) {

                // Do some stuff
                final Point3D point = result.getIntersectedPoint();

                if (isToggleTrue) {
                    changeCameraFocus(point);
                }
     }};}
```

The changeCameraFocus methods is:

```
  private void changeCameraFocus(final Point3D point)
  {
    camera.setTranslateX(point.getX());
    camera.setTranslateY(point.getY());
    camera.setTranslateZ(point.getZ());
    rotationCenter = point;
  }
```

The the variable rotationCenter is used as follows (Note cameraRotate is the Affine() registered to the camera), when the mouse is dragged across the screen:

```
cameraRotate.appendRotation(-angle, rotationCenter .getX(), rotationCenter .getY(), rotationCenter .getZ(), rotationAxis);
```

While this works in changing the focus of the object and center of rotation, the location it centers on is not where the mouse click occurred (although it is nearby and the object is visible).

Attempting to use the methods "getScene" and "getScreen" on the mouse event to get the coordinates leads to a location an order of magnitude away from the model and thus the display focuses away from everything.

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I believe I'm getting close to the solution, by re-writing the camera rotation method to the following

```
private void changeCameraFocus(Point3D point)
{
    Point3D newPoint = point.subtract(origin);
    cameraRotate.setToIdentity();
    cameraTranslate.setX(newPoint.getX());
    cameraTranslate.setY(newPoint.getY());
    modelCentre = point;
}
```

It fixes the issue, the downside is that from a usability perspective of the view is reset each time the mouse is clicked such that the original angle is displayed.